# Can't launch client eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i'm trying to launch the minecraft client using eclipse for Minecraft 1.8.9 mods, but when I try to launch client, I get:

```
'Launching Client' has encountered a problem.

Variable references empty selection: ${project_loc}
```

does anybody know what could be causing this or how to fix it?

edit: if It helps at all, i have created a github repo with my code [here](https://github.com/Josh-djs/mod-test/tree/main/java/jukebro/firstmod)

edit #2:

I selected the correct folder as pointed out by a comment, but now It does this:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit
```

then in console it says:

```
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
```

Comment: Looks like that launch requires you to have a project selected (in Project Explorer)

Comment: Click on the project so that it has a blue background.

Comment: What Greg says. `${project_loc}` is the project containing the currently selected resource and it might be the case that you have not selected a project resource. So better, also specify the project name, in your case probably `${project_loc:mod-test}`.