# eclipse client not launching

Tags: java, eclipse

When i try to run open the client in eclipse for Minecraft 1.8.9, i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleForgeHacks.searchCoremods(GradleForgeHacks.java:87)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:86)
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26)
```

i don't know what this means or how to fix it, so if anyone could help that would be appreciated.

by the way if it helps, you can find the github repo of the code [here](https://github.com/Josh-djs/mod-test)

Comment: Did you read [my comment on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031821/cant-launch-client-eclipse#comment116748113_66031821)? Did it or a comment of somebody else help? It is always a good idea to do a web search before asking a (new) question, e.g. `"class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader" net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleForgeHacks.searchCoremods(GradleForgeHacks.java:87)`.

Comment: sorry i didnt see the other comment, thanks for redirecting me :)